# Connect Metmask to ( local host ) port other than 8545

Tags: metamask

> How to connect metmask to genach-GUI having port : 7545 instead of
>   8545 .

Only network localhost :8545 is available on metamask

Is it done through  custom RPC network ?
If yes, then how should I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple ,

> metmask -> networks -> Custom RPC

```
Set
network Name : MyNetwork ,
New RPC URL : 127.0.0.1:7545 ( 7545 is my ganache port number )
```

Save
Now you are connected to ganache-GUI

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Metamask, you will also need to provide a chain-id. BY default, this is set to 1337. So, specify RPC URL as `http://localhost:7545` and
then enter the chain ID.

[Setup Ganache with Metamask. What and where is a Chain ID?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91072/setup-ganache-with-metamask-what-and-where-is-a-chain-id)