# Setup Ganache with Metamask. What and where is a Chain ID?

Tags: contract-development, truffle, blockchain, ganache, truffle-develop

I am following [these instructions](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/truffle-with-metamask).

The problem is that the above instructions don't mention `Chain ID`  and it appears `Chain ID`  is required to even make it work. Thus, I'm stuck.
[image]

What is the `Chain ID`? How do I get it **to set it**?

Comment: 1 - mainnet, 3 - ropsten, etc (see the full list [here](https://chainid.network/)).

Comment: I asked a similar question to the MetaMask team. You might have this error or a similar one even after stating the id as 1337. The reason: the RPC endpoint you're using is not https (at least, this told me the MetaMask support). He told me to also setup my local ganache network through ngrok (to have a dumb and temporary https endpoint).

Answer (score 19):

From the [`ganache-cli` docs](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli):

> --chainId: Specify the Chain ID ganache-cli will use for eth_chainId RPC and the CHAINID opcode. For legacy reasons, the default is currently 1337 for eth_chainId RPC and 1 for the CHAINID opcode. Setting this flag will align the chainId values. This will be fixed in the next major version of ganache-cli and ganache-core!

So, in your case, the Chain ID should be `1337`.

Answer (score 2):

I think your Metamask already has a local network so delete that network first and then try it.
it works for me.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the chainId use `ganache-cli -f <YourNODE> --chainId <newNumber>`  // You can see all commands using `ganache-cli help

Comment: how can I find out what my node is?

Answer (score 0):

As of at least `ganache v7.9.0 (@ganache/cli: 0.10.0, @ganache/core: 0.10.0)` you specify chain it with `--chain.chainId` if you are using the cli, otherwise it is **1337** by default

More info [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache)